# How to save data with gson in a json file?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

In my web application I succeed in displaying data in html table using mybatis. Now I want to save the records of the Mysql table in a json file and create an array of users, I used Gson, the problem is that just one record  saved in the file. Thanks.
Here the result in `file.json`:

```
{"data":
 [
 {"id":2,"Name":"Mike"}
 ]
}
```

**servlet.java**

```
SqlSession session = MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.getSession();
List<User> users = session.selectList("dao.UserDao.findAll");
for (User u : users) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        JsonWriter  writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\file.json"));
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("data");
        writer.beginArray();
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("id").value(t.getId());
        writer.name("name").value(t.getNom());
        writer.endObject();
        writer.endArray();
        writer.endObject();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

session.close();
```

Comment: because you're writing to the same file in every loop iteration. You need to  write the _list_ to the file, not each element.

Comment: if i understand you, i move the line "JsonWriter  writer=new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\file.json"));" before the line of for, but same result

Comment: Then you don't understand. You need to write the `list`! Gson will serialize it to JSON just fine by itself.

Comment: I'm beginner, it's the first example with json

Comment: gson.toJsonTree  to remove slash

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You write all the users in same file `C:\\file.json` so just the last iteration of the loop saved.

You can convert the object `List<User>` into json and write it once (no needed loop)

Example:

```
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("Output.json")) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    gson.toJson(users, writer);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i had all the users in the json file, but why the backslash with strings.I don't need to backslashs.                                        "[
{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Nancy\"},
{\"id\":2,\"detail\":\"Mike\"}
]"

Comment: If you save it as full object without change the string you can easy convert it back to your object, but it depend to your mission

Comment: do you have any solution about my first suggestion with looping ?

Comment: Use different file names or create one object that you want save (like List<user>) and save him as is.

Comment: Just remember to call writer.close() after that, otherwise result file will be empty.

Comment: use gson.toJsonTree if u do not want slash

Answer (score 5):

I was previously using outputStream.writeObject and Serializable with default writer/reader for saving object data. Because of problems with code sustainability I have been after something else. This is the result. That BufferedWriter is mandatory, otherwise write speed drops 8 times. Notice that UTF-8 declaration which is [default encoding of Json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_portability_issues). Not sure whether not declaring it is safe.

Example:

```
private void saveJson(Object object, Type type, String directory, String fileName) {

    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getDir(directory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
            fileName);
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } else {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        }

        gson.toJson(object, type, bufferedWriter);
        bufferedWriter.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (DEBUG) Log.e(saveJson, "saveUserData, FileNotFoundException e: '" + e + "'");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (DEBUG) Log.e(saveJson, "saveUserData, IOException e: '" + e + "'");
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.e(saveJson, "saveUserData, finally, e: '" + e + "'");
            }
        }
    }

}


private Object loadJson(Type type,  String directory, String fileName) {
    Object jsonData = null;

    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getDir(directory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
            fileName);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader streamReader;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } else {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        }

        jsonData = gson.fromJson(streamReader, type);
        streamReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "loadJson, FileNotFoundException e: '" + e + "'");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "loadJson, IOException e: '" + e + "'");
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "loadJson, finally, e: '" + e + "'");
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonData;
}
```

where Type for example:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() { }.getType();
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix to your code:

```
SqlSession session = MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.getSession();
List<User> users = session.selectList("dao.UserDao.findAll");
try {
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\file.json"));
    writer.beginObject();
    writer.name("data");
    writer.beginArray();
    for (User u : users) {
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("id").value(t.getId());
        writer.name("name").value(t.getNom());
        writer.endObject();
    }
    writer.endArray();
    writer.endObject();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, in the case that your User class looks like this:

```
public class User {
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

Then you don't need to code the adapter as Gson is able to automatically generate the JSON code for a class that only has primitives (ints, Strings, etc.). So your code would look as @roy-shmuli but only if you omit the data and keep only the array as List can be completely generated without an adapter. The JSON code generated would look like this:

```
[
    {"id":1, "name": "Mike"},
    {"id":2, "name": "Lucy"}
]
```

Hope it helps to the beginners.

Comment: Any idea about append the data in this json file each time ?