# Using SharedPreferences with for loop

Tags: java, android

To newcomers reading this, skip down to the part where I stop trying to use the SharedPreferences. It could have worked but apparently Gson started throwing security exceptions so I needed to start using intents. I'm still clueless.

I'm trying to save an arraylist of objects into a SharedPreferences file, by storing all of the object variables in the file. Here is some of the code exhibiting that.

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("lorBucks", lorandBucks[0]);
        editor.commit();
        //But wait there's more!
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getSharedPreferences("BoughtStuff", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        System.out.println("IS THIS THE CULPRIT: BOUGHTITEMS SIZE: " + boughtItems.size());
            editor2.putInt("Items Amount", boughtItems.size());
            editor2.apply();
        for(int i = 0; i<boughtItems.size(); i++) {
            editor2.putString(Integer.toString(i) + " name", boughtItems.get(i).name);
            editor2.putInt(Integer.toString(i) + " price", boughtItems.get(i).price);
            editor2.putString(Integer.toString(i) + " image", boughtItems.get(i).imageName);
        }
        editor2.commit();
    }
```

Now, this code obviously leaves out a lot of the action, but the important part is how it is saving values into the file. In a for(i) loop, it goes through an array of objects to save their variables under different identifiers.

Some of this code looks messy I know, but that's because of all of the debugging I've been doing trying to sort this problem out.

Now, here is an example of how I try to call these values:

```
 //Loading and Creating Bought Items
        SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences("BoughtStuff", MODE_PRIVATE);
        for(int i = 0; i<sps.getInt("Items Amount", 0); i++){
            System.out.println("Items Amount: " + sps.getInt("Items Amount", 0));
            boughtItems.add(new StoreItem(sps.getInt(Integer.toString(i) + " price", -1), sps.getString(Integer.toString(i) + " name", " "), sps.getString(Integer.toString(i) + " image", " "), layout, this));
            System.out.println(sps.getString("0 name", "DAMNIT!!"));
            System.out.println(boughtItems.get(i).name);
            System.out.println("NUMBER OF BOUGHT ITEMS: " + boughtItems.size());
        }
```

So I'm pretty screwed here, because somewhere along the way all of those values got lost (I've tried to display the object using toString()). But this is the soft blow, the entire app manages to crash at a later portion, when I'm actually calling these values into action. Here:

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        showItems();
    }
```

The showItems method:

```
public void showItems(){
        for(int i = 0; i<boughtItems.size(); i++){
            boughtItems.get(i).setUpShop();
            //final StoreItem[] stores = new StoreItem[1];
           // stores[0] = boughtItems.get(i);
           // final int[] c = new int[1];
           // boughtItems.get(i).getIb().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

              //  @Override
           //     public void onClick(View v){
           //         c[0] = 1;

          //      }
         //   });
         //   if(c[0] == 1){
         //       boughtItems.remove(i);
        //    }
        }
    }
```

And last but not least, the StoreItem.setUpShop() method, which works perfectly fine as long as it gets a good image file, but since the data isn't flowing properly it crashes the whole app. Here it is:

```
 public void setUpShop() {
        ib.setImageResource(getResourceID(imageName, "drawable", act.getApplicationContext()));
        ib.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1200));
        ib.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        TextView shopLabel = new TextView(act);
        shopLabel.setText(name + ": " + price + " Love Bucks");
        shopLabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        shopLabel.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
        layout.addView(shopLabel);
        layout.addView(ib);
    }
```

Now, I assume I'm just being very stupid with how I'm storing the data here (I'm an extreme beginner at coding apps and data persistence in general) so please let me know what I can do to make this work and what I should use in the future. I've tried my best to explain the whole situation but if there are any questions I would be happy to answer them.

So, I changed my approach and I now have a class here:

```
package com.example.lorand.saimibutton;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class StoreArrayHolder implements Parcelable {


        String price = "";
        String name = "";
        String image = "";

        protected StoreArrayHolder(Parcel in) {
            price = in.readString();
            name = in.readString();
            image = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Creator<StoreArrayHolder> CREATOR = new Creator<StoreArrayHolder>() {
            @Override
            public StoreArrayHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new StoreArrayHolder(in);
            }

            @Override
            public StoreArrayHolder[] newArray(int size) {
                return new StoreArrayHolder[size];
            }
        };

        public StoreArrayHolder(){

        }

        public String getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(price);
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(image);
        }

}
```

I use this to store the variables my objects need passed.
This is how I try to use the array between classes. I put this code in the onStop and onPause methods.

```
 private void sendIntent() {
        ArrayList<StoreArrayHolder> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < boughtItems.size(); i++) {
            StoreArrayHolder temp = new StoreArrayHolder();
            temp.setPrice(Integer.toString(boughtItems.get(i).price));
            temp.setName(boughtItems.get(i).name);
            temp.setImage(boughtItems.get(i).imageName);
            aList.add(temp);
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(this, PouchActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("list", aList);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

This is retrieving the array, I put this code in the onStart method.

```
private void getArrayList() {
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            if (getIntent().hasExtra("list")) {
                itemsInfo = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("list");
                System.out.println("FUCK YEAH IT WORKED!!!! " + itemsInfo.get(1).getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I get a nullpointer error meaning that none of the data got transferred, even though the list intent was technically sent!

Comment: Why have you choose to use SP? It's not the good way to save a list of objects.

Comment: I'm new to all this and it was the only way I knew how; what would you recommend?

Comment: Use DB e.g. [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) or save list to file as [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37916888/1979756).

Comment: Does getIntent().hasExtra("list") return true?

Use constants for names, not pure strings like "list". In second activity create "public final static String LIST_EXTRA = "list"" field and use it in send intent: i.putExtra(PouchActivity.LIST_EXTRA, aList) . And when getting extras: getIntent().hasExtra(LIST_EXTRA).

Comment: You should read tutorials or take some initial android courses (this level of knowledge are usually free to attend). You are asking about basic things.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Method to store array list in to preference (Here i use Gson to convert object in to json)

```
public void setListToPreferance(String key, ArrayList<OBJECT_OF_MODELCLASS> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Method to get list from preference (It will returns the ArrayList)
so you can directly get list from this method

```
public ArrayList<OBJECT_OF_MODELCLASS> getListProductModel(String key) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<OBJECT_OF_MODELCLASS>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<OBJECT_OF_MODELCLASS> list = gson.fromJson(prefs.getString(key, ""), type);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<OBJECT_OF_MODELCLASS>();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm using this to transfer an arraylist between classes, for the AppClass.getGson() part which class do I call, the one that recieves the arraylist or the one that saves it?

Comment: Thanks, I think it's starting to work, I'm having some problems with null pointer exceptions though when trying to reference the sharedpreferences, but I assume thats my own kink I have to work out

Comment: I think the Type is creating a security exception now however

Comment: Give the log exception text

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lorand.saimibutton, PID: 14908
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.lorand.saimibutton/com.example.lorand.saimibutton.StoreActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4294)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible

Comment: I also added SharedPreferences to the constructor because using it outside of the constructor resulted in a nullpointerexception... maybe it's time I try to use something other than sharedpreferences to transfer an array

Comment: you just want to pass data from one activity to another ? or want to store it permanently  in preferance

Comment: I'm just passing data from a "store" activity to an "items" activity, so you buy certain items and they pop up in your items activity. To do this Im passing an arraylist that will store all of the bought items.

Comment: so if you want to use preference you have to create a global class and initialize it in to Application class and store list and retrieve list otherwise you have to create model class Parcelable and pass it in to intent.put extra  and retrive it in another activity

Answer (score 0):

Pass ArrayListfrom one activity to another activity using Intent

1.Create a Model of array list with Parcelable implemantation

```
public class DemoModel implements Parcelable{

String price = "";
String totla_amount = "";

protected DemoModel(Parcel in) {
    price = in.readString();
    totla_amount = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<DemoModel> CREATOR = new Creator<DemoModel>() {
    @Override
    public DemoModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DemoModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DemoModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DemoModel[size];
    }
};

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getTotla_amount() {
    return totla_amount;
}

public void setTotla_amount(String totla_amount) {
    this.totla_amount = totla_amount;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(price);
    dest.writeString(totla_amount);
}
```

}

2. Inside the From activity from where you want to send data

   private void sendIntent() {

   ```
   ArrayList<DemoModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

   //Add data in to this list or use your list which you want to send

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConatctsModelActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("list", list);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

   }
3. Retrieve array list in To  second activity.

   ```
    ArrayList<DemoModel> list_in_second_activity = new ArrayList<>();
    private void getArrayLis() {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
       if (getIntent().hasExtra("list")) {
           list_in_second_activity = 
    getIntent().getParcelableExtra("list");
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay so actually I did some more research and this is exactly what I've been trying to do. Working on implementing it now, thanks for all your help. Will post update when I see what happens

Comment: Okay so something weird is happening, it gets past all of the if (getIntent().hasExtra("list") but crashes when I try to do System.out.println(list.get(0).getName); to see if it actually carries over the data. I can paste the code in an edit to my question